# DotNetNuke Event Viewer Stack Trace

Tags: dotnetnuke, stack-trace, event-viewer

Am getting the same error occurring over and over again in one of my dotnetnuke modules but the event viewer only gives me the error message, not the stack trace so I can track down to the function that is causing the problem but without the stack trace I can't identify the line. Any ideas how I can get the stack trace?

Comment: Have tried logging in as HOST and looking at log files but neither reveals any more informaion than the event viewer. Can't debug it as it's hosted on the server and am unable to recreate the error myself. It only seems to be experienced by some customers. I suspect this is because their accounts aren't set up correctly but without knowing where the error is happening I can't idenitfy what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

You can also view logs in /portals/_default/logs/

Open up any of the files labelled yyyy.mm.dd.log.resources in notepad and you should see a lot more detail about errors occurring on your site.

Comment: You can also change the DotNetNuke.Log4Net.config file in the root of your site from Errors to All to get more information.  (But revert the change when you're done.)

Answer (score 0):

Try logged in with your HOST account instead of an Admin to see more details about errors. Also, if you're running locally, try debugging the module to see what the exception is.